# How do I emulate inputs of a connected joystick / gamepad device?

Tags: c#, directx, hid, joystick, directinput

I don't even know if this is possible.

Basically I want to simulate gamepad inputs and I've already found some solutions here on stackoverflow. The common direction seems to be to create a virtual gamepad device that sends all the inputs.

What I want to implement is a tool that can send inputs for a gamepad device that is currently connected. So I can alternate between manual inputs from the gamepad and scripted input events that act as if they come from the same gamepad.

I'm using C#

Comment: Revisiting this question two years later. I'd probably solve the problem by writing a tool that creates a virtual device but also reads all input from the physical device to passthrough to the virtual device.